# Proper method to increment a void* by type size because cast results in temporary, not lvalue

Tags: c++

In upgrading the following old C++ code to compile under the modern Xcode 4.x compilers, I've found the original developer used a programming idiom that worked but should've been avoided -- it's now an error:

```
*((USHORT*) pvPixel)++ = uRG;   // copy red & green (2 bytes)
```

I see what was intended: copy the unsigned short (uRG) to the address pointed to by void pointer (pvPixel), then increment by the appropriate size (in the case above, 2 bytes).  Problem is that casting pvPixel results in a temporary, not an lvalue, which is no longer allowed.

The original developer used this idiom in dozens of places -- which I could rewrite in short time.  However, it would be nice to provide an ELEGANT and READABLE solution, rather than brute-force rewriting each and every occurrence.  I can think of several possible alternatives to a brute-force rewrite of each occurrence: macros, inline functions, perhaps a template?

My question is: is there any C++ syntax/language solution to this problem?  What would be an approach that would yield the clearest code for future developers?

(Two example functions, below):

```
void PrimSurfaceGDI3::mFillHLine( UINT uRGB, UINT uX, UINT uY, UINT uW )
{
    LPVOID pvPixel;

    if ( uW > 0 )
    {
        //  obtain a pointer to a specified pixel in the surface
        pvPixel = mPtr( uX, uY );

        USHORT uRG = *(USHORT*) &uRGB;

        BYTE uB = ((BYTE*) &uRGB)[2];

        LPVOID pvEnd = (BYTE*) pvPixel + uW * 3;

        while (pvPixel < pvEnd)
        {
            // The two lines below are now ILLEGAL in modern compilers because casting pvPixel to USHORT* or BYTE* results in a TEMPORARY, not an lvalue
            *((USHORT*) pvPixel)++ = uRG;   // copy red & green (2 bytes)

            *((BYTE*) pvPixel)++ = uB;      // copy blue (1 byte)
        }
    }
}
```

And below, this idiom is used in the reinitialization statement of the for loop:

```
void PrimSurfaceGDI3::mFillVLine( UINT uRGB, UINT uX, UINT uY, UINT uH )
{
    LPVOID pvPixel = mPtr( uX, uY );

    USHORT uRG = *(USHORT*) &uRGB;

    BYTE uB = ((BYTE*) &uRGB)[2];

    LPVOID pvEnd = (BYTE*) pvPixel + uH * muScan;

    // The reinitialization statement is now ILLEGAL in modern compilers because casting pvPixel to BYTE* results in a TEMPORARY, not an lvalue
    for ( ; pvPixel < pvEnd; ((BYTE*) pvPixel) += muScan)
    {
        *(USHORT*) pvPixel = uRG;       // copy red & green (2 bytes)

        ((BYTE*) pvPixel)[2] = uB;      // copy blue (1 byte)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "ELEGANT" but without rewriting the code?You want to overload operators and #define types just to make the code compile?

Comment: The best thing to do is simply turn it into a correct strongly typed container, rather than attempting to hack around it.

Comment: Granting that the whole void* wasn't a great way to have originally implemented the function(s), by "elegant" I'd like to avoid adding too many steps for each occurrence in the presently-written code. As @sfrabbit pointed out below, there's an in-line way to MAKE it work -- and it can be broken out for clarity.

Comment: @DeadMG -- in some of the code, (like above) there are loops that have one reference to the pointer, pvPixel, as a byte and some as a unsigned short.  Each case would need to get a DIFFERENT reference, right?

Comment: This sounds off. The original expression shouldn't result in a temporary. I'd suggest looking at the preprocessed output. Perhaps something, somewhere has typedef'd or defined `USHORT` to be something other than the obvious `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably one of the sounder ways to solve this problem is to rework things slightly. Change `mPtr` so it returns a pointer (or container reference) to a three byte type that has the three fields in it, and then use `std::fill_n` to fill that with the input RGB. Then the function shrinks to something like this (which gives your compiler a great chance to apply any appropriate optimizations):

```
void PrimSurfaceGDI3::mFillHLine( UINT uRGB, UINT uX, UINT uY, UINT uW )
{
    if ( uW > 0 )
    {
        ColorRep pvPixel* = mPtr( uX, uY );
        std::fill_n(pvPixel, uW, ColorRep(uRGB));
    }
}
```

Next, note that the original "optimization" is likely a de-optimization because of all the mis-aligned two-byte accesses it induces into the program.

If however you want to change as little as possible in the code, you accept that this code will likely not work on any architecture other than x86 (due to the mis-aligned accesses), AND you're willing to compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing` (which will probably be required due to casting to an unrelated type) then you can probably get away with `reinterpret_cast`ing to a reference:

```
*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*&>(pvPixel))++ = uRG;
```